# Notepad++ regular expression invalid

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've been hacked on some of my websites with code injection. I'm trying to find a line that contain part of the code injection with notepad++. Unfortunatly my regex does not work on notepad++:
I'm trying to work with this :

```
/^ *(.*(?:\$qV\=\"stop\").*) *$/igm
```

Notepad++ throw invalid regular expression :'(

I'm trying to find a line that contains $qV="stop"

**EDIT :** ok it's working but it doesnt find the text

Comment: Just use `^ *(.*(?:\$qv\[\"stop\"\]).*) *$` and do not check `Match Case` option. Please post a sample of the text you are trying to match/replace.

Comment: You are missing a matching `)`.

Comment: Try `^.*\$qv="stop".*` to match the whole line. However, I do not understand what it should look like in the end.

Comment: The end changes on each file but the beginning is always the same

Comment: @stribizhev Can you post this ^.*\$qv="stop".* as a answer it's working like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following regex:

```
^.*\$qv="stop".*
```

It will match the whole lines containing `$qv="stop"`.

Note that Notepad++ treats `^`/`$` anchors as line start/end anchors, and thus you do not need to specify the `/m` modifier.

Also, `/i` case-insensitive mode can be set with `Match Case` option. Uncheck it to use case-insensitive search mode.

A global search and replace is also performed using Notepad++ specific operation (*Replace All* button), thus, `/g` modifier is redundant.

Regex delimiters are not used, and thus are treated as literals (together with the modifiers).

Comment: I might have overdone with explanations, just your example regex was a bit unclear (unclear what you really pasted into the search field).

Comment: The explanations make me understand how regex works in notepad++, you've done great